# increment counter won't stop after value is met in if condition

Tags: javascript

For some reason when the condition is met which the counter stops at 4 the onclick function seems to still be add more price where it says if(j > 1 && j < 5) how can i stop the function once the condition is met. Thanks

```
function increment_bathClick() {
        if(j<4)
            j++;

            console.log(j);
            jQuery('#bath').val(j);

            var booking_type = jQuery('#booking_type').val();

            if(j > 1 && j < 5){

                //payAmt = parseFloat(bathrooms[i][booking_type]);

                payAmt =  payAmt + addbath * j;

                updateAmount(0,payAmt);

            }else if(j > 1 && i > 1){

                payAmt = parseFloat(bedrooms[i][booking_type]);

                payAmt =  payAmt + addbath * j;

                updateAmount(0,payAmt);

            }else{
                updateAmount(0,payAmt);
            }
}
```

Comment: Where is j initialised? Also missing at least a {}

Comment: I did add it here but somewhere in my code i have this: var j=1;

Comment: what is the values of j and i?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add some brackets, indention alone doesn't help ;-)

```
function increment_bathClick() {
    if(j<4)
    {
        j++;

        console.log(j);
        jQuery('#bath').val(j);

        var booking_type = jQuery('#booking_type').val();

        if(j > 1 && j < 5){

            //payAmt = parseFloat(bathrooms[i][booking_type]);

            payAmt =  payAmt + addbath * j;

            updateAmount(0,payAmt);

        }else if(j > 1 && i > 1){

            payAmt = parseFloat(bedrooms[i][booking_type]);

            payAmt =  payAmt + addbath * j;

            updateAmount(0,payAmt);

        }else{
            updateAmount(0,payAmt);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Axel adding the brackets fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
if(j<4)
  j++;
```

to this

```
if(j<4){
   j++;
}else{
   return;
}
```